# Why did only 31 engines ignite during Starship's static fire?

Tags: spacex, rockets, failure, spacex-super-heavy, ignition

What could be the reasons behind only 31 engines of the planned 33 engines igniting during Starship's recent static fire, given that the spacecraft is designed to have 33 engines and how could this impact the overall design of the spacecraft?

Comment: Elon Musk also mentioned that if it were a live launch, a loss of 2 engines would not be critical. Redundancy test could also be important in order to see how the rest of the system behaves when one or two engines have failed. A complex plumbing and propellant delivery could be a reason.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance I find Musks statement hard to comprehend - the space craft has 33 engines, 2 of which failed during a 6 second firing.  Redundancy is nice, but how much redundancy does it have left for the rest of the flight to space after those first 6 seconds?  He seems to be downplaying it there...

Comment: @Moo - The test flight of a Starship is without a payload. That should give them some redundancy with engines. But this is all theories, until the real thing.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance sure, but in reality 2 engines failed before the thing probably cleared the tower - payload or not, I wouldn't be dismissing it as "not critical" :)  If this was a full duration test burn, and 2 engines failed at separate points during that burn, I would have less of an issue with Musks response, but 2 engines in the first 6 seconds?  I'd be expecting a "yup, issue identified, lets fix it, do it again and gain more confidence before potentially throwing away an entire stack" at the very least.

Comment: @Moo - I did not quite get you. Musk did have a problem when his engine exploded. But why is a deadweight engine critical?

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance: If two engines fail every six seconds, you'll shortly have a *lot* of deadweight engines. Which would be critical.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance How many of those 33 engines are 100% redundancy?  How much redundancy was left after 2 failures in the first 6 seconds?  Whats the remaining factor for redundancy for an orbital burn? Thats my point.

Comment: @Moo - Sorry, I still don't understand you. Even the Russians in 1957 could afford to lose one engine on their R-7 during Sputnik launch. Musk can afford to lose 2-3 engines during a Starship launch. What "6 seconds" or "orbital burn" have to do with it?

Comment: The two engines did not fail "while running for 6 seconds", they failed at startup. Igniting a rocket motor is a pretty wild process. A running rocket motor is just a well running high performance device.

Comment: One engine aborted while starting up, one was locked out by the test team from even attempting ignition. 31 engines ignited properly and ran for the full six second test duration. They were not having "two engines fail every six seconds".

Comment: @Moo The *most critical* 6 seconds, yes? The 6 seconds during which engines are most likely to fail? Most plane crashes happen on takeoff or landing; you can't say that if 1% of planes crash during the first 60 seconds of flight, that means 60% crash during the first hour - it's more like if 1% crash within the first 60 seconds, then another 1% crash during the next 1-12 hours and another 1% crash within the last 15 minutes. (in reality it's less than 1%)

Comment: @user253751 They did not fail during operation. They failed during startup. During an actual launch, the computer would know the status of every engine before it gave the command to release the launch clamps. The computer would have criteria about how many engines are necessary, and can stop the launch if it's not ready. The Space Shuttle did the same, and several launches were aborted after engine start when one engine was not operating correctly. The difference is Shuttle needed all three for the first minutes of flight, while Starship could operate with less than 33.

Comment: please stop bumping your questions with minor edits.

Comment: @ErinAnne Indeed, especially the last edit adding "the fact that" into the first sentence is clearly detrimental because now that sentence has broken grammar (in addition to unnecessary word fluff).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One engine was shut off because it had a leaky fitting. The other shut itself down (auto aborted) when it was fired.

The static fire probably wasn't delayed because 31 was thought to be good enough and they are on a tight schedule. They are very keen to get this launch done and delay is not what they want (more specifically it's not what Elon Musk wants).

31 engines was probably enough to give them and the FAA sufficient confidence. No doubt there will be more tests to come anyway. Starship should be able to complete its mission with a few engines out, especially if it's not carrying much payload.

Aborting the whole test would have required all the propellants to be recycled (with losses so might have required top ups), investigations and remedial work of undefined duration to be carried out, installation of one or perhaps two new engines (do they have appropriate spares immediately to hand at Starbase?) new road closures to be arranged and more nitrogen purges (might need more LN). The actual list of knock on things that cause issues in the background is probably a lot longer than that. For example I bet there is a long long list of changes and improvements to the GSE that would potentially be impacted.

Comment: How do you know that "specifically" it's not what Musk wants?

Comment: I don't know for absolute certain, but given what I have seen and read about Elon Musk and from comments from people who have worked with him, it seems highly likely. He's a bit crazed about such things (I recommend Elon Musk's biography by Ashley Vance)

Comment: @Slarty - Unlike NASA, Musk seems happy (well, not happy, but at least sanguine) for these things to blow up, as long as they're part of a learning curve

Comment: @Richard yes true, if it doesn't break your not testing it hard enough. Musk has an unusual attitude to risk that was probably at least in part instilled by his grim childhood experiences in apartheid South Africa.

Comment: @Richard: That seems more a matter of an industrial approach. SpaceX plans to build rockets in volume, to keep costs down. This is very much the opposite of SLS. It keeps marginal costs down; losing an early-model Starship isn't that bad.

Comment: @MSalters - From what I can tell, NASA is operating on the principle that the best way to get into space is to start by burning a huge pile of money

Answer (score 20):

Note that this test gave them data on firing all engine position "types" (gimbaled center cluster and inner ring, fixed outer ring), the effects on the booster and ground equipment of attempting to start up 33 (later changed to 32) engines, and operating conditions with all but 2 engines operating, with 94% of the originally planned thrust and 32 (planned) engine ignitions. All they really missed out on was a test fire of the engine that shut down in startup and the one that they didn't fire, and the first of those would most likely have happened anyway even if they did abort the test to fix the other engine.

Proceeding with the test cost them only the propellant they already had loaded, and they got almost everything they possibly could get out of the test, so in cost/benefit terms the choice is clear.

Comment: Note that the planned thrust was "[~50% throttle](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1624412830446534656)". Launch is going to be...loud...

Comment: This answers the OP's second question, but it doesn't answer the first. Why were the two engines shut down? Suggesting that it was only a test of engine types would further suggest that the two engines were never meant to be fired, but if that's the case, why shut them down when it would make more sense to never plan to fire them in the first place?

Comment: @JBH One engine was manually disabled (probably some issue was detected) *prior* to testing, an other engine was automatically disabled by the computer on startup... Since SpaceX does not have time travel technology there is no way that they could have known of the automatic shutdown in advance and so they failed to not ignite it.

Comment: "Suggesting that it was only a test of engine types": nobody made such a suggestion.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff From the answer, "this test gave them data on firing all engine position 'types'." I apologize for not being more clear. My point was that the way the answer reads, it's unecessary to know why the engines failed simply because enough data was obtained that it didn't matter - except that it matters to the OP, which is the point of the question.

Comment: That was *one* of the things the test got them. And no, I didn't answer why the engine (singular) that shut down did so, and I'm not going to...as far as I'm aware, that information simply isn't available outside of SpaceX, NASA, and possibly a few people at the FAA. If the OP has an issue with a partial answer due to that, they can speak up themselves.

Comment: I have attempt to put all the answers into one and have added some detail to it not in any answer so that it fullly answers the question

Answer (score 15):

In general, the materials cost of getting a large system like that ready for test is **much** less than the people-and-infrastructure cost of setting up the test event.

At that point, they had already put in the people-and-infrastructure cost. The real question was likely not whether they could have the test that they wanted (because the answer was to that was no), but whether it was worth paying the relatively small marginal cost in order to get a large subset of the data they wanted back.

I don't know what SpaceX's specific costs look like here. But from working on other large-scale projects, late delays in test events mean you have already committed most of your cost for that event. Picking a path forward is a balancing act between the high costs of pausing or restarting the test and the value of the data that you might miss from things left out in last-minute changes.

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch it's lovely that you've edited literally every answer to this question, some more than once, but "the cost of propellant" you've added is part of the "materials cost" fectin was comparing the "people-and-infrastructure" cost to.  You've made the answer less correct.

Comment: Okay. I agree @ErinAnne

Answer (score 11):

Seeing how a system responds with an error (1 engine not fired, 1 aborted) actually provides useful information as well. For example, it shows that the software and hardware in place to shut down an individual engine works properly - otherwise an engine problem could easily spread to other engines and possibly cause loss of the spacecraft.

In addition, working through engine failure is designed into these types of rockets. For example, at least one time [Falcon 9 launched successfully despite failure of an engine](https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/03/spacex-set-to-launch-the-same-falcon-9-rocket-for-the-fifth-time/). In that instance, the first stage was not successfully recovered, but the primary mission succeeded.

On the other hand, if you only have one engine then failure of that engine is failure of the mission.

Comment: At one time I worked on an autonomous vehicle (for a university competition, not Tesla). Some time during testing something caused the control loop to freeze for a second and the robot ran head-first at full speed into a literal brick wall. Of course, the most expensive component (LIDAR) was at the front. Never found out why that was, but after it happened again, we added a secondary control system that would stop the robot if it sensed it was closing in too fast on a wall. I'm not sure what this has to do with rockets, but failed tests can be informative. One of the competitors' caught fire.

Comment: @user253751 The old autonomous vehicle competitions were fascinating looks into why the problem was so difficult and how many approaches you can take to try to solve it

Comment: @Kevin btw this was like a 40cm cube-ish robot designed to move 10cm foam cubes for a competition, nothing like a car, if that's what you were thinking.

Comment: @user253751 Makes sense, they also did full scale actual car races through mountain roads and stuff, but those were large scale productions, not really college projects